# USB drive can't be detected. Tried lsusb, dconf-editor, disks utility, sudo blkid.

Tags: ubuntu, usb, detection

got a new USB (Kingston 32gb) 
After first use and then ejecting it on Ubuntu 14.04 it's not detectable anymore. 
tried lsusb - doesn't show up in the list (tested on my mouse usb receiver and works just fine)
installed dconf-editor and checked the settings, is auto-mountable on startup or upon insertion. 
disks utility doesn't show anything except HDD partitions, doesn't help at all.
Tried sudo blkid as well, doesn't show the usb path. only hdd partitions.

Have no idea what might have gone wrong with it. 
Don't know what's the formatting on the usb and even if it's damaged for some reason I believe it still should be detectable at least, not to mention mounting.

Any help would be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I would guess that it's a hardware problem.

Comment: but it worked the first time. that's whats bugging me :/

Comment: Try on Windows... but I guess it won't work, neither. It happens that it works one time, but not more. May be a hardware failure.

Comment: Tried in windows as well, couple of times with regedit and through disk management. Nothing. Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 1):

the strategy is to compare the difference between the first and the second `dmesg` command. type dmesg and keep in mind the **end of the output** of the first dmesg, then attach the usb and type dmesg again. once again see the **end of the output**. if there was no change the device is killed. if the output is something like:

```
[60457.728379] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 46 using ehci_hcd
[60457.873169] scsi32 : usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[60458.874291] scsi 32:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB DISK 2.0     PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[60458.888297] sd 32:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[60460.306626] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] 7819264 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 GB/3.72 GiB)
[60460.307182] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[60460.307194] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[60460.307681] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[60460.307692] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[60460.313816] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[60460.313831] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[60460.314750]  sdb:
[60460.320113] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[60460.320129] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[60460.320140] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[60474.716807] sdb: detected capacity change from 4003463168 to 0
```

the device is still working and there are issues with kernel modules or security

Answer (score 0):

use `dmesg` then attach device then use `dmesg` again and see the output. if there is an output it is at least not an hardware error...

alternatively you can use `tail`

Comment: This gives a long output, anything specific i should look for?

Comment: when using `dmesg` the end of ouput after the second `dmesg` the second time (after the USB was attached) is the interesting part

Comment: When the events are not logged, they are not logged and that's as much as I can do.
I guess it is a hardware problem after all. Found every single internal storage and USB mouse receiver except the usb drive so. Pretty solid proof I guess. Thank u